# Express: serving static files in express using app.use() not working on * route

Tags: html, css, express, http

I am trying to serve static html and css files using express on any route. The files are present in public folder in the same directory the express file is present. The express code is given below:

```
const express = require('express')
const path = require('path')

const app = express()

// app.use('*', express.static('./public')); // Not Working
// app.use('/', express.static('./public')); // Working but only limited to home route
app.use(express.static('./public')); // Working but only limited to home route

app.listen(5000, () => {
  console.log('server is listening on port 5000....')
})
```

Answer (score 4):

if the folder public in the same root with your node app use:

```
app.use(express.static('public'))
```

To create a virtual path prefix (where the path does not actually exist in the file system) for files that are served by the express.static function, specify a mount path for the static directory, as shown below:

`app.use('/static', express.static('public'))`

Now, you can load the files that are in the public directory from the /static path prefix.

http://localhost:3000/static/images/kitten.jpg
http://localhost:3000/static/css/style.css

However, the path that you provide to the express.static function is relative to the directory from where you launch your node process. If you run the express app from another directory, it’s safer to use the absolute path of the directory that you want to serve:

const path = require('path')
app.use('/static', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')))